# Airflow: Can't set 'default_timezone' to 'system'

Tags: airflow

Running puckel/docker-airflow, modified build so that both environment variables, and airflow.cfg have:

```
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE=system
```

and

```
default_timezone = system
```

accordingly.

But in the UI, it still shows UTC, even though system time is EAT. Here is some evidence from the container:

```
airflow@906d2275235d:~$ echo $AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE
system
airflow@906d2275235d:~$ cat airflow.cfg | grep default_timez
default_timezone = system
airflow@906d2275235d:~$ date
Thu 01 Aug 2019 04:54:23 PM EAT
```

Would appreciate any help, or an advice on your practice with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/timezone.html):

> Please note that the Web UI currently only runs in UTC.

Although UI uses UTC, Airflow uses local time to launch DAGs. So if you have for example  schedule_interval set to `0 3 * * *`, Airflow will start the DAG at 3:00 EAT, but it in the UI you will see it as 0:00.